# React Hook - useEffect clarification

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a newbie trying to understand what is going on here. Would be thankful to anyone able to explain what I am missing here. I am following an example I found in the internet. Why is Steve (index value 1) not appearing/rendering and logged in the console.

As I understand,

- Initially state variable index is initialized to 0.
- length of NAMES array is logged as 3.
- Component is rendered. Hence we see, Hello Mark!.
- Side-effect is triggered, inside which, 0 === (3-1) check fails.
- SetTimeout called. State variable index will be set to 1 after 2 seconds.
- However, next line will log index value of 0.
- After 2 seconds, since dependency value (index) had changed, useEffect called. 1 === 2 fails, setTimeout called again.
- State variable index will be set to 2 after 2 seconds,
- However, I expected index to be logged as 1 and Greet component to be rendered with the name Steve - what am I missing here

**App.js**

```
import Greet from './Greet';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const NAMES = ["Mark", "Steve", "Glen"];

function App() { 
  const[index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  console.log(`NAMES.Length : ${NAMES.length}`);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(index === NAMES.length - 1){
      console.log(`index in condition : ${index}`);
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(()=> setIndex((index)=>index+1), 2000);
    console.log(`index after setTimeout : ${index}`);
  },[index]);
  return (
    <div className="App">     
        <div className="content">
            <Greet name={NAMES[index]} />        
        </div>        
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Greet.js**

```
const Greet = ({name}) => {
    const message = `Hello, ${name}!`;  
    console.log(message);
       
    return ( 
        <div>{message}</div>  
    );
}
export default Greet;
```

**Console.log**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you did wrong in setIndex().

```
// setTimeout(()=> setIndex((index) => index + 1), 2000);
setTimeout(() => setIndex(index + 1), 2000);
```

Then you can see "Steve" in console.log

Comment: Yes, we can use arrow-function inside of setState. But this case is wrong use